# Screen BlackOut in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm creating a PreferenceScreen in runntime. But the screen blackout when trying to scroll through.

For `ListView` there is a state to avoid this sort of situation,

```
android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
```

But no such state for PreferenceScreen.

How can I avoid screen blackout in PreferenceScreen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this thing.

```
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(4, 26, 55));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but perhaps this answer will help those who find it:

Try this:

In your Android Manifest file, add "@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings" to your preference activity.

Example:

```
<activity
        android:label="@string/cube2_settings"
        android:name=".CubeWallpaper2Settings"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.WallpaperSettings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_wallpaper"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="unspecified" >
</activity>
```